# AppWidgetHostView touch events not working properly

Tags: android

As you know AppWidgetHostView doesn't handle long press well and when using registerForContextMenu(host view) it doesn't open.

I created a custom host view derived from AppWidgetHostView and override touch events to show context menu.

But the side effects are bad, not because my code, but because the structure of the AppWidgetHostView and how touch events passed and treated differently based on the nature of the widget not my code.

For example, the code below fires down & up events when taping over ( Clock digital ) widget, which by the way doesn't have an attached activity to it. But both down & up events don't get fired with ( Calendar ) widget, instead it opens calendar activity.

So, Calendar widget consumes the events, unlike the Digital Clock.

In case you thought about onInterceptTouchEvent it gets worst and worst... where Up event doesn't get fired when I tap over Digital Clock widget, which causes the context menu to appear as if it's a long tap.

It's been two days running around reading & applying & testing but I can't find a solution that suits all type of widgets.

Thank you

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    switch(ev.getActionMasked() ) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mDownUp = 0;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            mDownUp = 1;
            break;
    }

    return true;
}




@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent (MotionEvent ev) {

    switch(ev.getActionMasked() ) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mDownUp = 0;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            mDownUp = 1;
            break;
        }

    return false;
}
```

By the way, I didn't use / override both onInterceptTouchEvent and onTouchEvent together, I tried each one separately.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem whan use [openlauncher](https://github.com/OpenLauncherTeam/openlauncher/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/benny/openlauncher/core/widget/WidgetView.java). I start reseach system app widgets and found in [calendar widget](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/+/master/res/layout/appwidget.xml?autodive=0%2F%2F) that adding

```
android:focusable="true"
android:clickable="true"
```

to widget layout was help.

Comment: Thank you Pavel, but the problem is not in a widget I created, it's in the widgets I host in my application.

Comment: Launcher use custom https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/+/master/src/com/android/launcher3/LauncherAppWidgetHostView.java with https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/+/master/src/com/android/launcher3/CheckLongPressHelper.java, try to use it the same.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I'll give them a try.